# Control Memory Allocation

Tags: eigen

I'm thinking of using Eigen for a Wwise (audio middle-ware) plugin that I'm building and was wondering if it's possible to override the method Eigen uses for heap allocations?

Wwise plugins typically operate in a pre-allocated memory pool, providing a number of macros for alloc/free, new/delete.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this can only be achieved by linking to library redefining `malloc`, `free`, and `realloc` and leveraging your own memory allocator. This means that your allocator will be used thorough your application. If your allocator does not return pointers aligned on 16 bytes, then you must tell it to Eigen with `-DEIGEN_MALLOC_ALREADY_ALIGNED=0`.

Comment: Ah OK thanks for the quick response - I take it I can't just override the allocation methods defined in Memory.h then?

Comment: oh, sure, you can also patch Eigen's source code. Simply redefine `aligned_malloc`, `aligned_free`, and `aligned_realloc` as you please! But that's less convenient.